# How to reduce android application loading time using threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to make an application which gets running applications properties like (process names,icons,memory etc) and display them in listview.

Since I am executing them in main thread this is taking too much time.
How can I create more threads in this sample loop?
(I am new to android programming)

```
//would like to run this loop in parallel
for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) {
// calculations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using multiple AsyncTasks and execute tasks using  `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` or use multiple threads for processing in parallel.

**AsyncTask**

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //would like to run this loop in parallel
        //You can also start threads 

        for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) {
            // calculations
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Using **Threads**

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < processes.size() /2; i++) {
        // calculations
        }
    }
});

Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = processes.size() /2; i < processes.size(); i++) {
        // calculations
        }
    }
});

thread1.start();
thread1.start();
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.. I tried both of your methods but it does not display list in AsyncTask and crashes in threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi I think you have one loop to iterate which is the data got from any Web Service.

 - Basically all the long running process which are need for UI changes can be run inside the AsyncTask, which will create background threads.

class AsyncExaple extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //What ever the long running tasks are run inside this block
        //would like to run this loop in parallel
        for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) {
// calculations
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
};


To call this AsyncTask do as follows

AsyncExaple asyncExaple = new AsyncExaple();
asyncExaple.execute();


If you still want to use the Threads use below code:

 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }).start();
```